# Running docker for windows for local development with an Ubuntu OS in production

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

My production instance is running under Ubuntu 16 while my local machine runs under Windows 10.

In order to have a setup close to my production, I use VMs (vagrant, virtualbox, homestead). Btw, my application is a Laravel app so homestead is the route to go as per its documentation.

Since I have multiple applications that have different specifications (different OS version, different app versions), I need to set multiple VMs as well. Since VMs are resource-heavy, it tends to slow down my machine in time.

That then, I came across Docker. Will Docker for Windows and create containers and images base on my app's specification suffice or do I still need a VM then create docker containers from there?

Below is a diagram

Windows running Docker for Windows

[image: Windows running Docker for Windows]

Windows running Ubuntu VM with Docker

[image: Windows running Ubuntu VM with Docker]

Answer (score 1):

Docker-Desktop will by default start and run a Linux VM in the background of your Windows System.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

- Hyper-V and Containers Windows features must be enabled.

You can also use WLS/2 which is basically the same thing.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

Jens